# Is the Wii U Pro Controller compatible with the Nintendo Switch?

Tags: controllers, wii-u, nintendo-switch

Can the Wii U Pro Controller be connected to the Nintendo Switch console to use the controller in games or applications?

Answer (score 14):

### No.

From the [Nintendo Switch FAQ](http://www.nintendo.com/switch/faq/):

> ### What controllers work with Nintendo Switch?
>
> There are multiple controller options for the Nintendo Switch console, including Joy-Con controllers and the Nintendo Switch Pro Controller. Compatible controllers will vary per game, so be sure to check game details. You can see available accessories here.
>
> **Controllers from previous Nintendo platforms are not supported.**

(emphasis mine)

As noted above, the Switch has its own Pro Controller.  It's more expensive than the WiiU Pro Controller, likely because it has motion controls and a Near Field Communication (NFC) reader (for Amiibo) built in.

Answer (score -1):

It can work, but it'll require some money. You may need an 8bitdo adapter or something of that nature, using it, [Check out My Mate VINCE](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChY9Cgv-iyPDvf1Bkyx20OQ) for tutorials on such things - these types of adapters tend to work with Wii, Xbox & Playstation controllers as well! But i doubt it'll work with the wii u gamepad since it has it's on OS.